# Ionic 4 not showing external images

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to display external images but image loading only works well in

> ionic serve

My code is like this:

```
<img [src]="user?.img.url" />
```

or

```
<div *ngIf="user"> 
 <img [src]="user.img.url" />
</div>
```

but the images are not been loaded in mobile

if I copy the link contained in `user.img.url` and write a code like this:

```
<img src="'https://res.cloudinary.com/ddon9fx1n/image/upload/v1567797308/rvnpdvy9dsj9ws8tiatj.jpg'" />
```

then it always works in `ionic serve` or in mobile

With some images all the above code works... I am using Cloudinary to storage media files

Comment: Are you getting any console errors in the developer console when the images don't load? What is the response in the network tab when the browser tries to load the image?

Comment: Hello, Im not getting any error in logcats (android studio) when I open the page with the images..

Comment: I found the error.. the image url was starting with http not https.. now it works again..

Comment: ¡bueno mi amigo!